# Figure inside of starred Chapter with alphabetic numbering

Tags: captions, chapters

I'm writing a book using LaTeX, and I have five main chapters. What I need is to add additional starred chapters with alphabetical enumeration, like (Annexe A, Annexe B...), so I can add figures to these chapters with the following caption:

> Figure A-1 : this is a caption

But when I add a figure after the starred chapter it always take the fifth chapter number which is five. How can I solve this?

EDIT : this is the sample code:

```
    \documentclass[parskip=full,12pt,a4paper,twoside,frenchb,openany,fleqn]{book}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\listoffigures
\chapter{chapter 1}
\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{images/figure5-20.jpg}
  \caption{caption 1 }
\end{figure}
\chapter*{annexe A}
\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \includegraphics{images/figure5-20.jpg}
  \caption{caption 2}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

I want to get Figure 1-1 : Caption 1 And Figure A-1 : Caption 2.

Comment: Please post a minimal working example which shows your problem.

Comment: @MMA : post edited, I've added a sample code.

Comment: What is the order of chapters? 1-2-3-4-5-A-B-C-D-E? Or 1-A-2-B-...?

Comment: Put `\appendix` and then `\chapter{annexe A}`

Comment: It's 1-2-3-4-5-A-B ... From A-B I've used stared chapter for styling purposes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a simple way to do this. (I'm assuming since you want 'Annexe' your document is in French.

```
\documentclass[parskip=full,12pt,a4paper,twoside,frenchb,openany,fleqn]{book}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx} % remove [demo] for real images
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[francais]{babel}
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{\thechapter-\arabic{figure}}
\begin{document}
\listoffigures
\chapter{}
\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{images/figure5-20.jpg}
  \caption{caption 1 }
\end{figure}
\appendix
\chapter{}
\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \includegraphics{images/figure5-20.jpg}
  \caption{caption 2}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```